# How to access specific item key

Tags: reactjs

I have this state

```
this.state = {
          isdone: '',
          items: [],
          currentItem: {text:'', key:''},
        }
```

I am storing unique key in the currentItem and I need to iterate through these items to set isdone value so I tried like this

```
completeItem = key => {
    this.state.items.map(item => {
                if (this.state.currentItem.key === key) {
                    this.setState({isdone: 'is-done'})
                }
            })
}
```

but this does not change the isdone value, how to change the isdone value correctly ?

Comment: I want to update `isdone` for specific `key`

Comment: Souldn't you be asking if (item.key === key) ?

Comment: @JosephD. yes I store unique key for each item in the key

Comment: So if one of the items in the array-porperty 'items' of your object contains the key given as parameter of the completeItem-function you want the property 'isdone' of your object to be set to 'is-done'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your state structure seems kinda off. Based on the code you provided, it sounds like you're trying to accomplish some sort of check-list component. If that is the case, you should not be using a single `currentItem` or `isDone` state.

Instead what you really want is to give each item in the array their own `isDone` property. That way you can accurately toggle the property of each item. Similar to an actual check-list.

Try something like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-galileo-yp7hj

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [
        { key: 1, text: "walk dog", isDone: false },
        { key: 2, text: "clean fridge", isDone: false }
      ]
    };
  }

  handleComplete = key => {
    const itemsClone = [...this.state.items];
    const foundItem = itemsClone.find(item => item.key == key);
    foundItem.isDone = true;

    this.setState({
      items: itemsClone
    });
  };

  renderItems = () => {
    const { items } = this.state;

    return items.map(item => {
      return (
        <div>
          <span>{item.text}</span>{" "}
          {!item.isDone ? (
            <button onClick={() => this.handleComplete(item.key)}>
              Mark Complete
            </button>
          ) : (
            <span>Completed!</span>
          )}
        </div>
      );
    });
  };

  render() {
    return <div>{this.renderItems()}</div>;
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

In the code above, you'll find that we only have one property being tracked in our state and that's the list of items. Additionally each item has their own `isDone` property along with a key and text value.

Now to actually mark an item as complete, I've introduced a button with a `onClick` handler. Upon rendering each item in the list to create our mark-up, each item will have their own button, and we use the `handleComplete` method which accepts a key as an argument. The function will use that key to find the corresponding item in our state and toggle its `isDone` property to true.

Answer (score 2):

Setting `isdone` to a specific `item` instead of `state.isdone`.

```
const items = this.state.items;

items.map((item, index) => {
  if (this.state.currentItem.key === key && item.key === key) {
    this.setState({
      items: [
        ...items.slice(0, index),
        { ...item, isdone: 'is-done' },
        ...items.slice(index + 1, items.length)
      ]
    })
  }
})
```